# REST API or Java SDK, Which is preferable for monitoring Oracle Cloud Compute VM?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

Which one makes process easier, minimum lines to code and easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Java SDK](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/javasdk.htm) will be easier, assuming you are used to coding in Java. With using the REST API directly, you have to managing the [signing logic](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/signingrequests.htm) yourself, as well as be familiar with HTTP semantics like URI, path, query params, headers, body, etc. The Java SDK (and the [other OCI SDKs](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/sdks.htm)) abstract that all away for you.